# Make stroke path tips fading fading on both tips in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

how could i achieve to have a brush like the one in the picture with both tips fading? I checked in the brush window but I could only affect (alpha and size) the ending tip of the brush stroke..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a graphic Tablet, such as a Wacom Bamboo or Wacom Intuos, in order to achieve those types of strokes.

Without a tablet, you are limited to fading only one end of the brush.

Answer (score 2):

Scotts answer is not exactly true.
Yes, you can only fade out the end, if you want to draw freely, but in this case you can replicate this effect without a tablet.

And this is how you do it:
[image]

1. Create a path to follow along with the stroke
2. Set the brush options you want to be affected to `pen pressure`.
3. Change to the path or the direct selection tool (<kbd>A</kbd>)
4. Select the path
5. Right click the path and chose `Stroke Path`
6. Choose `Brush` and hit the checkmark for `Pen Pressure`
7. Hit `OK`

Photoshop simulates the pen pressure as seen in the brush preview window. It starts with a pressure of 0, goes up to 100 and back to 0. All of this in a linear way, following the path. You will not be able to manipulate this behavior, but it is handy for exactly the case, described in the question.