# Brush stroke a path with thin-thick-thin in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path, line-art, brush

So i know I can use brush simulate a brush stroke from thin-thick-thin 
[image: Thin-Thick-Thin]

and thick to thin with the fade option

[image: Thick-Thin].

Is there a way to simulate a brush stroke so the path will have thick end points and thin middle. I mean with out a tablet of some sort.

In addition, can i brush a path starting from the end point and not from the start anchor point?

If there is no way to do it in Photoshop, can I do something similar in Illustrator?

Thank you

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6198/make-stroke-path-tips-fading-fading-on-both-tips-in-photoshop

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in **Photoshop** to use the `Fade` feature on both ends of a stroke. The *only* way to accomplish that is via a tablet with brush dynamics and pressure.

With **Illustrator** there are a couple methods to alter the width of a stroke.

- You can use the **Width Tool** to manually click-drag areas along a path to increase or decrease a stroke's width.

[image]

- You can choose a **Profile** for a stroke in the **Stroke Panel or Control Panel** (This essentially just applied the width variables in a predetermined fashion.)

[image]

Photoshop contains no features which are similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

Illustrator has a width tool for strokes (CS5+): [Illustrator Quick Tip: Adjusting Line Width with Stroke Profiles](http://wegraphics.net/blog/tutorials/illustrator-quick-tip-adjusting-line-width-with-stroke-profiles/). So you can make the path and then edit the end point widths.

I am not sure how you would achieve the pen pressure without a tablet.